# I want to give security to my PHP code from copy

Tags: java, php, security

I want such a script or logic so that if somebody has a copy of my code, they can only access/run it if they have my unique key, otherwise they get an error. Is there any way to do like this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking "How do I keep my business logic secure on my server?" If so you should look into using a framework like Laravel. Learn how to use it and how to serve it on a server.

Comment: no. i am asking for client side. i know in laravel security. but i want it in php

Comment: Firstly this question could be many things, you can use session controls and cookies to try and secure your code or like richard suggested using a framework to take care of this but you will still need to ad your own security too.

Comment: Yes, that is my question security. what kind of security i can create? session and condition is inner thought, but i want secure my code when some one not using my key and copy my code

Comment: Why would anyone get your php file in the first place?

Comment: That's why I brought up Laravel, you can add the Auth middleware to a controller that lets a user download a copy of your php code. Never heard of anyone doing that before though.

Comment: i am also using laravel richard, but according to requirement, i have to do this

Comment: You can pass the data between several servers who only do part of the calculation each. It will slow it down but to get the full PHP code you need to hack x number of servers and piece together y number of php files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody has a copy of your PHP code they can run it. As PHP is not compiled, the possessor can read and edit the code as well; so even if you put in something that checks against a secret key, they could simply remove it. If you encrypt the code into an unreadable state, it’s also in an un-runnable state.

So, in brief, there really isn’t a way to give working PHP to another person in a way that they can’t simply run it. If you’re looking to sell a product of some sort, your best bet is probably to run it as a service so the end user never actually sees the code.

The closest you might hope for would be to make it difficult to read, i.e. with meaningless variable and function names and zero white space; but that won’t stop somebody who really wants it, (and who knows how to work some basic refactoring utilities), and only adds significant complication to your own work